# Data binding of TextBlock.Text in DataTemplate

Tags: data-binding, windows-phone-7, datatemplate

I have a panorama control in which the panorama item is binded to a data template.
The data template is:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <Grid Height="546" Width="432">
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="FromValueTB" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            FontSize="40" 
            TextAlignment="Right" 
            Padding="0,0,10,0"/>
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="FromValueUnitTB" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Margin="0,50,15,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            FontSize="21.333" 
            TextAlignment="Right" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="ToValueTB" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Margin="0,74,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            TextAlignment="Right" 
            FontSize="40" 
            Padding="0,0,10,0"/>
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="ToValueUnitTB" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Margin="0,119,15,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            TextAlignment="Right" 
            FontSize="21.333" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <TextBlock 
            x:Name="RestltTB" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Margin="0,144,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            TextAlignment="Center" 
            FontSize="16"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The panorama control is created as:

```
<controls:Panorama 
    x:Name="mPanoramaControl" 
    Title="convertors" 
    Height="728" 
    Width="480" 
    Style="{StaticResource MyPanoramaStyle}">
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
</controls:Panorama>
```

The problem I'm facing is that I'm not getting how to bind the data to my custom class such that if I modify the properties in my class, the text will change.

My custom class is something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string line1{get;set;}
    public string line2{get;set;}
    public string line3{get;set;}
    public string line4{get;set;}
    public string line5{get;set;}
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for your user interface to update when the properties of your class change, you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. There's a good article on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) that walks you through how to do this.

Assuming that the data context for the control that is using this DataTemplate is set to an instance of your class, then you also need to bind the **Text** property to the relevant property: `Text="{Binding line1}"`